How to turn, say the x-axis, into an ordinal axis with x-data as textual labels using tikzlibrary datavisualization?
Background
Assume you have data like these in the data-section of datavisualization, which could also come from a file,
        date,birds      
        30/10/2023,1200
        02/10/2023,1229
...

or
        species,birds       
        spec4,1200
        spec1,1229
...

\datavisualization provides two visualizations, scientific axes and school book axes, which both require xy-data.
Question
It's no big deal to replace the textual x-data by a counter, to introduce a simple ordinal scale. But how to preserve or access the original x-data AND put them as labels on the x-axis instead of 1,2,... ?
Attempts
The code below provides \pgfdeclaredataformat{ordinalX}, which replaces x-data by a simple counter NX.
I know, I could write a list, e.g. via ticks={major at={1 as spec4,...}}, by hand into the x axis statement. But that's no nice idea when processing data, already given in the data section.
Looks like I have no idea about scope of data, access, data structures used here or even guessing the right pgfkey from the pgfmanual alone wrt datavisualization.
Can this only be solved by introducing a global variable, e.g. as pgfkeys, l3, "array", data-object etc.? And if so, will the declared format put the extracted original x-data there?
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\newcounter{NX}

% ~~~ introducing ordinal values for x ~~~~~~~~~
%     converts (date,birds) into (NX,birds) in (x,y) world
\pgfdeclaredataformat{ordinalX}
    {}
    {}
    {#1,#2}
    {   % ~~~ new x-values: one-by-one ~~~~~~~~~
        \pgfmathaddtocounter{NX}{1}
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/x}{\theNX}     
        % ~~~ preserving the y-data ~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/y}{#2}         
        % ~~~ original x-data, to be treated as labels ~~~~
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/mylabel}{#1}       
        % ~~~ storing NX, y and (?) mylabel ~~~~~
        \pgfdatapoint
    }
    {}{}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [
        scientific axes=clean,
        x axis={label=X,
                ticks={label=mylabel} % can't put date as labels
        },      % rather it likes a list ?from data section?
        y axis={label=birds},
        all axes=grid,      
    ][  
        visualize as line,
    ] data [format=ordinalX] {
%       date,birds              % skipping header
        30/10/2023,1200
        02/10/2023,1229
        06/11/2023,980
        09/11/2023,570
        13/11/2023,308
        16/11/2023,2590
        20/11/2023,11700
    }
    %     TEST / Bypass ?
    % ~~~ if I had access to, say, /data point/mylabel here ...
    %     I might be able to iterate and place date as labels
    info{
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,7}
            \node[rotate=90,anchor=east,teal] 
                at (visualization cs: x={\x},y={-2e3}) {X-label};
    }
    ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I found a solution using and adapting Jake's solution from 2013. Key points:

most things happen in statement x axis={..., ticks={...
it calls a typesetter
it styles the nodes for the labels (rotate etc.)
the typesetter relies on a global TeX list, which functions like an array
within the declared format ordinalX it appends to said list
I use a LaTeX counter instead of the predefined TeX \@tempcnta, see here on StackExchange
\makeatletter and \makeatother are included, but don't seem to make an effect, probably due to the different counter used

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\newcounter{NX} % <<< using LaTeX counter istead of \@tempcnta

\makeatletter
    % ~~~ introducing ordinal values for x ~~~~~~~~~
    %     converts (date,birds) into (NX,birds) in (x,y) world
    \pgfdeclaredataformat{ordinalX}%
        {} % No catcode changes
        {\xdef\label@list{}}%                       initialise a global label list
        {#1,#2}%                                    data format
        {%
            \pgfmathaddtocounter{NX}{1}%            advance
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/x}{\theNX}%store counters result as x-data 
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/y}{#2}%    the y-data (birds)          
            \xdef\label@list{\label@list,"#1"}%     append label to list
            \pgfdatapoint
        }%
        {}{}

    % ~~~ typesetting the x-axis: putting labels instead of 1,2,3, ... ~~~~~~~~
    \def\ticksfromlabellist#1{%
        \pgfmathparse{{\label@list}[#1]}%   retrieve label one by one   
        \pgfmathresult%                     result: text, i.e. 30/10/2023
    }    
\makeatother


% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization [
        scientific axes=clean,
        x axis={
            label=Date,
            ticks={                                             % NEW
                step=1, 
                tick typesetter/.code=\ticksfromlabellist{##1}, % typesetting labels, replacing 1,2,3,...
%               style={text height=1ex},                        % for proper vertical alignment
                node style={rotate=90,anchor=east,teal},        % rotating etc.
            } 
        },  
        y axis={label=birds},
        all axes=grid,      
    ][  
        visualize as line,
    ] data [format=ordinalX] {
%       date,birds              % skipping header
        30/10/2023,1200
        02/10/2023,1229
        06/11/2023,980
        09/11/2023,570
        13/11/2023,308
        16/11/2023,2590
        20/11/2023,11700
    };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


